# Having an issue with a variable in java

Tags: java

Having an issue compiling. The compiler is saying a variable is not used even though I use it on line 25.

> Error:
>   [line: 21]
>   Warning: The value of the local variable pay is not used

```
// CreatePayroll.java takes wages and hours from file and creates pay file.
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class CreatePayroll {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
//Scanner for input file
      File inputFile = new File("employees.txt");
      Scanner fin = new Scanner(inputFile);
//Printwriter for output file
      File outputFile= new File("payroll.txt");
      PrintWriter fout = new PrintWriter(outputFile);
//read input file creates new file
      while ( fin.hasNextLine() ) {
        String firstName = fin.next();
        String lastName = fin.next();
        double wage = fin.nextDouble();
        double hours = fin.nextDouble();
        //Calculates pay
        if (hours > 40) {
          double pay = (wage*40)+((hours-40)*(wage*1.5));
        } else {
          double pay = wage*hours;
//last line to print to out file
          fout.println(firstName + " " + lastName + " $" + pay);
        }
      }
//cleanup
      fin.close();
      fout.close();
      System.out.print("DONE! See 'payroll.txt'.");
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Read about the scope of a variable.

Comment: Your declaraion of `pay` within the `if` block isn't visible within the `else` block.

Comment: Please don't tag your question with _[FIXED]_, instead accept the best answer that helped you solve your problem. If none of the existing answers were of help, post your own solution as an answer and accept that.

Answer (score 5):

You have a severe scope problem: you're declaring the pay variable **twice** inside your both the `if` and `else` statements, meaning that these very local variables are only visible within these blocks. Don't do that. Declare pay above the if/else block so it can be used throughout the method.

so change:

```
if (hours > 40) {
    double pay = (wage*40)+((hours-40)*(wage*1.5));
} else {
    double pay = wage*hours;
    //last line to print to out file
    fout.println(firstName + " " + lastName + " $" + pay);
}
```

to:

```
// declare pay prior to the if/else blocks
double pay = 0.0;
if (hours > 40) {
     pay = (wage*40)+((hours-40)*(wage*1.5));
} else {
     pay = wage*hours;
}

// get the line below **out** of the else block
fout.println(firstName + " " + lastName + " $" + pay);
```

Comment: then how would it interact with the if else to properly calculate pay due?

Comment: @Sean: I thought that I showed that in my code above.

Comment: It didn't show  up the first time I loaded the page. Thank you very much for the help!